# Creating a checksum for passed in parameters in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a checksum for my payment gateway. The checksum should be in this format:

```
key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|||||||||||salt
```

I need to leave 11 pipes between the email and the salt.

In my controller I created a method:

```
require 'digest/sha2'

def getChecksum(key, txnid, amount, productinfo, firstname, email, phone, surl, furl)
  String str = key + '|' + txnid + '|' + amount + '|' + productinfo + '|' + firstname + '|' + email + '|' + phone + '|' + surl + '|' + furl+ '|'+ '|'+ '|'+ '|'+ '|'+ '|'+ '|'+ '|' + 'salt'
  Digest::SHA512.hexdigest( str )
end
```

I called this method in my controller:

```
hash: getChecksum(
              key: 'key_value',
              txnid: '4',
              amount: '2000',
              productinfo: 'first sales',
              firstname: 'John',
              email: 'johndepp@gmail.com',
              phone: '123456789',
              surl: 'http://someurl.io',
              furl: 'http://someurl.io')
```

But now I am getting a "wrong number of arguments" error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 9)    
def getChecksum( key,  txnid, 
amount,  productinfo,  firstname, email, phone, surl, furl)
```

I think all the parameters are considered as a single one. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Ruby isn't Java. We don't need, or use `String str =...` and `getChecksum` should be `get_checksum` as methods, like variables, are written in snake_case.

Comment: @theTinMan Yes...you are right...But learned quite a lot with this single question..Thank you all for the help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at how you're writing your code and see if we can make it more Ruby-like and hopefully more production-worthy.

You wrote this:

```
def getChecksum(key, txnid, amount, productinfo, firstname, email, phone, surl, furl)
  String str = key + '|' + txnid + '|' + amount + '|' + productinfo + '|' + firstname + '|' + email + '|' + phone + '|' + surl + '|' + furl+ '|'+ '|'+ '|'+ '|'+ '|'+ '|'+ '|'+ '|' + 'salt'
  Digest::SHA512.hexdigest( str )
end
```

First, ick.

- Methods and variables in Ruby are snake_case, not camelCase. ItsAReadabilityThing.
- We don't define variables using `String str =...`. Ruby can figure out what type of variable it is 99.99% of the time, so `str =...` is sufficient.
- Think about how you're using fixed-strings and values. `'|'` is your separator, so define it as such:

  ```
  SEPARATOR = '|'
  ```

  And you need eleven of them as a divider, so define that:

  ```
  DIVIDER = SEPARATOR * 11
  ```

I'd write the code more like this:

```
require 'digest/sha2'

SEPARATOR = '|'
DIVIDER = SEPARATOR * 11 # => "|||||||||||"

def checksum_1(key, txnid, amount, productinfo, firstname, email, phone, surl, furl)
  str = [key, txnid, amount, productinfo, firstname, email, phone, surl, furl].join(SEPARATOR) + DIVIDER + 'salt'
  Digest::SHA512.hexdigest(str)
end
```

But even that can be improved upon.

When we have more than three parameters it's time to refactor and clean up the parameter list. There are many ways to do it, but using a hash is the most common:

```
def checksum_2(params)
  str = params.values_at(
    :key, :txnid, :amount, :productinfo, :firstname, :email, :phone, :surl, :furl
  ).join(SEPARATOR) + DIVIDER + 'salt'

  Digest::SHA512.hexdigest( str )
end
```

Using `values_at` is a nice way to extract the values of the keys in a hash. They come out in an array in the same order of the keys.

The problem now is that a parameter could be missing and Ruby won't catch it. Named parameters are the new-hotness for dealing with that, but for older Rubies, or to get an idea how it might be done in other languages, we can look at the keys received, then their associated values, and if things don't look good raise an exception rather than return a bogus value.

To make things easier I'm going to use Active Support's [`blank?`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#blank-questionmark-and-present-questionmark) method, found in the Core Extensions:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'
def checksum_3(params)
  required_values = [:key, :txnid, :amount, :productinfo, :firstname, :email, :phone, :surl, :furl]

  missing_keys = required_values - params.keys
  fail ArgumentError, "Missing keys: #{ missing_keys.map{ |k| ":#{ k }" }.join(', ') }" unless missing_keys.empty?

  missing_values = required_values.select{ |k| params[k].blank? }
  fail ArgumentError, "Missing values for: #{ missing_values.map{ |k| ":#{ k }" }.join(', ') }" unless missing_values.empty?

  str = params.values_at(*required_values).join(SEPARATOR) + DIVIDER + 'salt'
  Digest::SHA512.hexdigest(str)
end
```

Here's how the calls to the various versions of the method look, along with the associated checksum that's returned:

```
c1 = checksum_1('key_value', '4', '2000', 'first sales', 'John', 'johndepp@gmail.com', '123456789', 'http://someurl.io', 'http://someurl.io')

c2 = checksum_2(
  key: 'key_value',
  txnid: '4',
  amount: '2000',
  productinfo: 'first sales',
  firstname: 'John',
  email: 'johndepp@gmail.com',
  phone: '123456789',
  surl: 'http://someurl.io',
  furl: 'http://someurl.io'
)

c3 = checksum_3(
  key: 'key_value',
  txnid: '4',
  amount: '2000',
  productinfo: 'first sales',
  firstname: 'John',
  email: 'johndepp@gmail.com',
  phone: '123456789',
  surl: 'http://someurl.io',
  furl: 'http://someurl.io'
)

c1 # => "fcf4e21c6e711808a6984824f09552dccc5c4378b55720c88b3abd4a1904931b8d883beaef51edec705a9d8b0ccd3ba898a0d4c05f75bd41fa3b90f0df7b5c79"
c2 # => "fcf4e21c6e711808a6984824f09552dccc5c4378b55720c88b3abd4a1904931b8d883beaef51edec705a9d8b0ccd3ba898a0d4c05f75bd41fa3b90f0df7b5c79"
c3 # => "fcf4e21c6e711808a6984824f09552dccc5c4378b55720c88b3abd4a1904931b8d883beaef51edec705a9d8b0ccd3ba898a0d4c05f75bd41fa3b90f0df7b5c79"
```

While we still have to pass in the same amount of information, using the hash allows us to see what each parameter is being assigned to, resulting in self-documenting code, which is a very important thing for long-term maintenance. Also, the hash doesn't require a specific order of the parameters, making it easier to write the code calling it; I usually know I need certain things but can't remember what order they're in.

That's all my take on how to write this type of code. See "[Ruby 2 Keyword Arguments](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments)" for a similar write-up on the same topic.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time in putting this all together..I now feels like  I understand it all like a breeze....Changed the chosen answer to this as this explains a lot in detail...Couldn't thank more...Have a great day...

Answer (score 2):

You are sending a single hash as the parameter, instead you need to send the values only (without keys). Also no need to declare the type `String str`, you should review your Ruby fundamentals, I'm guessing you come from another language.

```
# You are calling this
getChecksum(key: 'key_value', txnid: '4', ...)
# which syntactically equals this, a single hash as a parameter
getChecksum({key: 'key_value', txnid: '4', ...})
# Instead, send the values alone
getChecksum('key_value', '4', ...)
```

Comment: With this many arguments a hash is probably preferable. You could get the best of both words by using keyword arguments: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments

Comment: Welcome to Ruby! You will find it entertaining and behind a strong community ready to help.

Comment: WRT to the method signature.  You can either pass the values from the controller to your method as a comma delimited parameter list; or you can keep what you have in the controller and re-factor your target method to take a hash and extract the keys. Something like `def getChecksum( myhash ) ; mykey = myhash[ :key ] ; mytxnid = myhash[ :txnid ] ; . . .; end`

Comment: That is because the code formatting in comments is limited.  Each of those ';' would instead be a line break if I were writing it.  But, a ';' is a valid statement terminator. So, the example is correct Ruby.  Just not idiomatic.

Comment: @JamesB.Byrne didnt meant its bad code in anyway..I just meant the method with my scenario as mine has quite some values..

Comment: All the more reason to tease each one out into its own variable so that its value can be inspected and manipulated without affecting any of the others.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you would define the method with keyword arguments:

```
def getChecksum(key:, txnid:, amount:, productinfo:, firstname:, email:, phone:, surl:, furl:)
  str = key + '|' + txnid + '|' + amount + '|' + productinfo + '|' + firstname + '|' + email + '|' + phone + '|' + surl + '|' + furl+ '|'+ '|'+ '|'+ '|'+ '|'+ '|'+ '|'+ '|' + 'salt'
  Digest::SHA512.hexdigest( str )
end
```

Then you can call it with a hash like you are currently.

I think this looks a bit cleaner, though:

```
def get_checksum(key:, txnid:, amount:, productinfo:, firstname:, email:, phone:, surl:, furl:)
  str = "#{key}|#{txnid}|#{amount}|#{productinfo}|#{firstname}|#{email}|#{phone}|#{surl}|#{furl}||||||||salt"
  Digest::SHA512.hexdigest(str)
end
```

Or perhaps:

```
def get_checksum(key:, txnid:, amount:, productinfo:, firstname:, email:, phone:, surl:, furl:)
  str = [ key, txnid, amount, productinfo, firstname, email, phone, surl, furl ].join("|")
  Digest::SHA512.hexdigest("#{str}||||||||salt")
end
```

You can learn more about keyword arguments, including how to give keywords default values to make them optional, here: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments

Comment: This last solution looks much elegant without those pipes. Thanks.